# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError trying to read avro files in Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, avro

Trying to read avro files in Apache Spark, I was receiving this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.avroFilterPushDown()'

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This error happened for me because I was using an older version (3.0.1) on that doesn't exist this new configuration. After I upgrade my local spark version to 3.1.2 fixed the problem